# Obtain the second and third position of a day, with different hours

Tags: postgresql, datetime

Focused on entry, lunch entry and exit, company exit

Sample data:

[image: Table]

Expected result:

[image: Expected result]

```
Select x."ID", MIN(x."FECHA") as "1pos", null "2pos", null "3pos", MAX(x."FECHA") as "4pos"
from sirha7.v_marcaciones x 
WHERE x."CEDULA" = '0401219282' AND CAST(x."FECHA" AS date) = '2022-12-27'
GROUP BY x."ID", DATE_TRUNC ('day', x."FECHA")
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: Please avoid attaching pictures of data and code. You can edit the question and add the data sample and your example result as text instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`array_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) to collect all `"FECHA"` [ordered](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) per `"ID"` in a [`with` common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html), then access them by their index. In case some of your `"ID"`s don't have 4 `"FECHA"`s to their name, you can use [`array_upper()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#id-1.5.8.25.6.2.2.14.1.1.1) to get the index of the last element:

```sql
with cte as 
 (  select 
      x."ID", 
      array_agg(x."FECHA" order by x."FECHA") as all_fecha_per_id
    from sirha7.v_marcaciones x 
    WHERE x."CEDULA" = '0401219282' AND CAST(x."FECHA" AS date) = '2022-12-27'
    GROUP BY x."ID", DATE_TRUNC ('day', x."FECHA")   )
select 
  y."ID",
  all_fecha_per_id[array_lower(all_fecha_per_id,1)] as "1pos",
  all_fecha_per_id[1] as "1pos",
  all_fecha_per_id[2] as "2pos",
  all_fecha_per_id[3] as "3pos",
  all_fecha_per_id[4] as "4pos",
  all_fecha_per_id[array_upper(all_fecha_per_id,1)] as "4pos"
from cte as y
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/vACRmdKB)